# do I need to implement google Transaction API for taxi booking app google action? because no payment flow in google action

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

I am working on booking ride skill in google action. Our Google Action allows the user to book a seat on a ride. Google action is not responsible for deducting any amount of money to book that seat on the ride. It merely sends a request to the backend that the authenticated user wants to go from point **a** to point **b**, and for the same, he wants to book a seat on the ride. Now the success of the seat booking is based on the kilometer credit he has in the user account. The user account is only accessible via an Android or iOS application of mobile application And it is via this android or iOS application the user can manage their Kilometer credits.
Hence, as explained above, we are not making any monetary transactions via our Google action.

can you please help me I need to implement google Transaction API in google action?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating 'transaction-like' behavior that doesn't use money directly, you should use the [reservations transaction](https://developers.google.com/assistant/transactions/physical/dev-guide-physical-reservations) format which provides a lot of the same behavior of a monetary transaction without the exchange of money. When you receive the reservation on your server, you can handle it by changing credits.